# Why does my Webpack bundle include jQuery twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack

I set up a parent module with 2 submodule dependencies. The parent module has no specified jQuery dependency, but each submodule specifies jQuery ^3.3.1 as a dependency (results in 3.4.1 for each submodule). I Webpacked the parent module and then I see in the generated bundle file that jQuery 3.4.1 is included twice. What should I be doing so that the same version of jQuery isn't included twice? I did try the splitchunks plugin and it did generate chunks but jQuery was still in there twice. I thought that Webpack is supposed to automatically analyze dependencies in the module graph and optimize the bundled code? I haven't yet tested NPM peer dependencies or the Webpack de-dupe plugin. I'm also wondering if there's something about jQuery itself to where Webpack can't/decides not to de-dupe automatically?

In both submodules' index.js files, I'm using:

```
import $ from "jquery"
```

In each submodule's package.json I specified:

```
"dependencies": {
"jquery" : "^3.3.1"
}
```

Then I did a npm install on each submodule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that module resolution can automatically happen downwards (into child folders) of an entry point folder, but not upwards (in module folders outside of the entry point folder). I found that I needed to "tell" Webpack about these other module locations by adding a "resolve" object to Webpack.config:

```
resolve: {
        modules: [
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/modules/pagetype/node_modules"),
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/modules/sitewide/node_modules"),
          path.resolve(__dirname, "src/modules/template/node_modules"),
          "node_modules"
        ]
      }, // resolve
```

Answer (score 1):

```
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            // fix every jQuery to our direct jQuery dependency. Shariff 1.24.1 brings its own jQuery and it would be included twice without this alias.
            'jquery': __dirname + '/node_modules/jquery/',
        },
    },
};
```

Note -happens because Shariff 1.24.1 defines `jQuery` as its own dependency instead of defining it as peer dependency in the `package.json`.

[Refrence](https://github.com/heiseonline/shariff/issues/222)

Comment: Thanks Parth. I just did "npm list" on my parent module and I don't see Shariff anywhere there. I just tried a build with this resolve in webpack.config and got error that jquery could't be resolved in my submodules. Plus, I don't want to necessarily force every module to use the same version of jQuery (even though in practice yes they likely will).

Comment: Just saw that the dedupe plugin is no longer part of Webpack, so I won't try that

Comment: So I've come to understand that if my submodules are physically within the parent module's folder, then NPM can dedupe the dependency since to begin with it will only install the dependency once. Thus my bundle gets only 1 copy of jQuery. Now to figure out if I can and how to allow for modules saved outside of the parent module's folder, time for testing